# Building a ranking system on Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django soccer app with following models and I want to make a queryset (or something else) to build a "ranking" table on my template (pass as context):

- Round (round_number, round_name)
- Game (round, team1, team2, goals, faults)
- Team (name)
- Player (name, team)
- Goal (game, player)
- Fault (game, player)

Having these models with these fields, how can I build a ranking table with following information?

Team | Wins | Losses | Games Played

Comment: It would be better if you shared what have you tried so far. So people here can help you find the best approach.

Comment: Problem is that I don't even know where to start, I don't know if I need to create another model in order to put entries for each team score, or if I can just calculate it with a method and something like this

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your data model makes some things unintuitive, so if you have flexibility there, you might want to consider a change.

For example, if you want to get a list of games and know *who won the game* it's not trivial because the game table doesn't have a column for the winning team, or information about how many goals each team scored. Instead, you have to join to the goals, and the players, and then the players teams. (Huge caveat that I can't test this code, and it's complex enough that there are might be errors.)

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q, F, Case, When

games = Game.objects.annotate(
    team1_goal_count=Count('goals', filter=Q(goals__player__team=F('team1'), distinct=True),
    team2_goal_count=Count('goals', filter=Q(goals__player__team=F('team2'), distinct=True),
    result=Case(When(Q(team1_goal_count__gt=team2_goal_count), then=F('team1')),
                When(Q(team2_goal_count__gt=team1_goal_count), then=F('team2')),
                default=None)
)
```

The above will give you a queryset of games annotated with a count of each teams goals and the id of the winning team in the `result` column (`null` in the case of a tie)

If you want to get a list of teams with their win/loss/draw record ordered by winning percentage, you have to join to the games and similarly compute the scores (Note, this is so complicated, I don't know if it even works as I've written it):

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef
# Use the `games` query from above
scored_games_1 = games.filter(team1_id=OuterRef('pk'))
scored_games_2 = games.filter(team2_id=OuterRef('pk'))

# Need to group by the OuterRef('pk')
scored_games_1 = scored_games_1.values('team1')
scored_games_2 = scored_games_2.values('team2')

# Annotate the counts and select on that column
scored_games_1 = scored_games_1.annotate(count=Count('pk')).values('count')
scored_games_2 = scored_games_2.annotate(count=Count('pk')).values('count')

won_q = Q(result=F('pk'))
lost_q = Q(result__isnull=False) & ~Q(result=F('pk'))
tied_q = Q(result__isnull=True)
teams = Team.objects.annotate(
    games_won=Subquery(scored_games_1.filter(won_q)) + Subquery(scored_games_2.filter(won_q)),
    games_lost=Subquery(scored_games_1.filter(lost_q)) + Subquery(scored_games_2.filter(lost_q)),
    games_tied=Subquery(scored_games_1.filter(tied_q) + Subquery(scored_games_2.filter(tied_q)),
    winning_percentage=F('games_won') / (F('games_won') + F('games_lost') + F('games_tied'))
).order_by('-winning_percentage')
```

Including a column in `Game` that is the id of the winning team is a denormalization that makes all of the above so much simpler. Making `Game` and `Team` a many to many relationship (even though there can be only 2 teams) would make things easier as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I do have flexibility to change my models, can you please update your answer with some recommendations regarding the structure?

Comment: Well, my last paragraph had two suggestions, but the honest truth is that from a distinace, it's impossible to say exactly what the right choices are.